# Fantasy short story featuring a character named Pepsi

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

10-15 years ago I read a short story collection that I would like to read again.

One story had a character named Pepsi. He was a boy of about 10-15 years old. There was a wonderful passage about the wonder of a boy of that age.

There was another story about a race car driver.

Wish I knew more.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this?

Bones of the Moon ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0312873123)) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bones_of_the_Moon))

> Living in New York, Cullen James's best wishes were being fulfilled. Her best friend marries her; she travels in Europe; she has a baby daughter. But strange dreams begin to intrude.
>
> By night, in dreams, she begins to visit a strange land called Rondua, where the sea is full of fish with mysterious names, where she and a huge, behatted dog escort a young boy named Pepsi across places such as the Northern Stroke, the Mountains of Coin and Brick, the Plain of Forgotten Machines.
>
> As her days become more disjointed and episodic, her dreams grow in intensity, and she learns more about the adversary she and her dream friends race against, searching for the last of the Bones of the Moon. Bit by bit, the events in Rondua start affecting her life on earth, intersecting in unpleasant, then frightening ways.

Comment: It may very well be **Bones of the Moon**. I will search now for a copy to read. Thank you for replying. Over the years I have searched and have only come back to my unanswered question. Bridget